# How can I change primary key on SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am going to change the primary key on SQL Azure. But it throws an error when using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to generate the scripts. Because every tables on SQL Azure must contains a primary key. And I can't drop it before create. What can I do if I must change it?

Script generated

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[mytable]') AND name = N'PK_mytable')
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mytable] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_mytable]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mytable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_mytable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF)
GO
```

Error message

```
Msg 40054, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
The statement has been terminated.
Msg 1779, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
Table 't_event_admin' already has a primary key defined on it.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I ran into this exact problem and contacted the Azure team on the forums. Basically it isn't possible. You'll need to create a new table and transfer the data to it.

What I did was create a transaction and within it do the following:

- Renamed the old table to OLD_MyTable.
- Create the new table with the correct Primary Key and call it MyTable.
- Select the contents from OLD_MyTable
  into MyTable.
- Drop OLD_MyTable.

You may also need to call sp_rename on any constraints so they don't conflict.

See also: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ssdsgetstarted/thread/5cc4b302-fa42-4c62-956a-bbf79dbbd040

Answer (score 8):

upgrade SQL V12 and heaps are supported on it. So you can drop the primary key and recreate it.

Comment: Completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: This is actually a good answer.  I dropped my old pk and then created a  new primary key in about a minute.  In the past, I had to do the renaming and importing table trick.  It was time consuming.  V12 has a lot of more SQL Server features including support for FullText indexing.

Comment: this question is about Azure.  Not a standalone database.

Comment: Yes, in Azure SQl DB v12, this is supported

Answer (score 4):

I appreciate that this may be late in the day for yourself, but it may help others.

I recently came across this issue and found the least painful solution was to download the database from Azure, restore it locally, update the primary key locally (as the key constraint is a SQL Azure specific issue), and then restore the database back into Azure.

This saved any issues in regards to renaming databases or transferring data between them.

Comment: What a wonderfully simple answer. Implementing the export and recreation was a bit of a brain twist as it was my first time with all of that, but in the end, it was so elegant.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following scripts. Change it to suit for your table def.

```
EXECUTE sp_rename N'[PK_MyTable]', N'[PK_MyTable_old]',  'OBJECT'

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Temp_MyTable](
[id] [int] NOT NULL,
[text] [text] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
[id] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON))

INSERT INTO dbo.[Temp_MyTable] (Id, Text)
SELECT Id, Text FROM dbo.MyTable

drop table dbo.MyTable
EXECUTE sp_rename N'Temp_MyTable', N'MyTable', 'OBJECT'
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is outdated because changing PK is already supported in latest version of SQL Azure. And you don't have to create temporary table.

Comment: Source? I cant figure out how to do this.

Comment: Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/tables/delete-primary-keys?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: In the header there is a row: Applies to: SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and later, Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance. It means it is supported in SQL Azure