# azure db drop pk and add a new one

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have MS SQL database on Azure , and I want to drop my Primary key constraint and add another column as a primary key ,  every time I try to run the script to drop the primary key I get the error:

" Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again."

by running this script:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.key_constraints WHERE type = 'PK' AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Paypaltransaction') AND Name = 'PK_PaypalTransaction')
   ALTER TABLE dbo.PaypalTransaction
   DROP CONSTRAINT PK_PaypalTransaction
GO
```

Then I go and try to create another primary key :

```
-- add new primary key constraint on new column   
ALTER TABLE dbo.PaypalTransaction 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_PaypalTransactionId
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PaypalTransactionId)
GO
```

and I get this error:
"Table 'PaypalTransaction' already has a primary key defined on it."

I understand the error's , but I can't delete the primary key because it appearently has to have one , and I can't add a new one because  I already have one .  Am I just stuck forever and ever and ever with the wrong column as my primary key :'(

I see [This Question here that is the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432187/problems-changing-pk-datatype-using-entityframework-codefirst-migrations-on-azur)  and they ended up dropping the table and creating a new one - no way that is the only way to do this , that is just silly.

Comment: [How can I alter an existing Primary Key on SQL Azure?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6937/how-can-i-alter-an-existing-primary-key-on-sql-azure/6943#6943)

Comment: It would appear that it is just that silly, by design. See this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645145/how-can-i-change-primary-key-on-sql-azure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy over from the DBA.Se answer:

Q5) Can the primary key of a table be modified when is enforced via the clustered index if the table is populated?
A: No. Any operation that converts a populated clustered index into a heap will be blocked in SQL Azure, *even if the table is empty*:

```
create table Friend (
    UserId int not null,
    Id int not null identity(1,1),
    constraint pk_Friend primary key clustered (UserId, Id));
go
insert into Friend (UserId) values (1);
delete from Friend;
go
alter table Friend drop constraint pk_Friend;
```

As a side note: the constraint can be modified if the table is *truncated*.

The workaround to change the PK constraint of a populated table is to do the good old [`sp_rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) trick:

```
create table Friend (
    UserId int not null,
    Id int not null identity(1,1),
    constraint pk_Friend primary key clustered (UserId, Id));
go
insert into Friend (UserId) values (1);
go

create table FriendNew (
    UserId int not null,
    Id int not null identity(1,1),
    constraint pk_Friend_New primary key clustered (Id, UserId));
go

set identity_insert FriendNew on;
insert into FriendNew (UserId, Id) 
select UserId, Id
from Friend;
set identity_insert FriendNew off;
go

begin transaction
exec sp_rename 'Friend', 'FriendOld';
exec sp_rename 'FriendNew', 'Friend';
commit;
go

sp_help 'Friend';
```

The `sp_rename` approach has some issues, most importantly being that permissions on the table do not carry over during the rename, as well as foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested and it seems that on SQL AZURE V12 it is possible!

Comment: V12 is completely different technology that V.pre12. It supports almost everything the standalone supports.